# SaveDefinitions->True changes the displayed image

Tags: manipulate, bugs, image

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

I have a `Manipulate[ ]` that displays an image with a superimposed `Locator` object. It works fine when I have `SaveDefinitions->False` but when I try to change `False` to `True` the image object changes (and is not displayed correctly). Here's an image which I load in and call `img`

[image: my tif image]

The Manipulate is this:

```
 img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKudh.png"];
 Manipulate[img, {p, Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> False]
```

If you evaluate this, it displays the image with a locator object in the bottom left. All is well. But if you now evaluate

```
 Manipulate[img, {p, Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

it displays not the image, but a long list of numbers starting with:

```
Image[{{244,243 ....
```

In trying to debug, I note that `ImageQ[img]` is `True` after evaluating the first `Manipulate` but is `False` after evaluating the second. This does not occur with all images (I tried a jpeg) but seems to happen with my .tif files (like the one above). *Mathematica* 9.0.1 Mac OS. I just noticed that when I uploaded the image, it was converted to a .png file. The same (bad) behavior occurs with this file as well.

The same bad behavior is still happening in version 10.0.2.

Comment: Both Manipulates work for me in 8.0.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: Both work fine on my installation -- V9.0.1 running on OS X (10.6.8)

Comment: m_goldberg Wow... that's weird. I just tried (again) with a new launch and it's still happening -- though my system seems identical to yours. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I see no difference PC WinXP, Math 9.0.1.0

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour. 9.0.1 on OS X 10.8.3. When `SaveDefinitions` is set to `True`, the structure of `img` is changed from `Image[RawArray["Byte",{{...` to `Image[{{...}}, Byte, ColorSpace -> ..., Interleaving -> ...]`. I have no idea why the symbol `img` is modified.

Comment: -rm -rf That's probably the cause of the change in the ImageQ[ ] output. I guess this means I'm not going crazy after all (at least in this instance).

Comment: No problem in version 7 under Windows 7.

Comment: @bills I can reproduce it on OSX too. Mathematica 9.0.1 and OSX 10.8.3. On the same computer with Mathematica 8.0.4 everything works fine.

Comment: halirutan -- great idea. I just went back to 8.04 and you're right, it works fine there. Thanks! I guess I can redo my larger program in the old version.

Comment: Reproduced in 10.1.0 under Windows.  I am removing the osx tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
img = Image@ImageData@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKudh.png"];
Manipulate[img, {p, Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

or this

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKudh.png"];
Manipulate[
 img = Quiet[img /. ColorProfileData[] -> Automatic], {p, Locator}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I think the problem is how the image is stored when it is imported.  I do not know anything about this, so perhaps others better versed in image processing will know what it is.  Here is an image of the `FullForm` of `Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKudh.png"]`:

[image: FullForm]

When `Manipulate` converts it to some saved format, it must be mangling the `ColorSpace` option.  It gets converted to `ColorSpace -> ColorProfileData[]`, which is invalid.  Setting it to `Automatic` seems to work, except that in generates a message somewhere in the `Manipulate`; hence the `Quiet`.

It seems to be a bug, but in the meantime, you have a workaround.

Comment: thanks for this. It's just happened to me again, and your `ColorProfileData` fix works perfectly.

Comment: Another work-around that may or may not be applicable depending on how one uses the image: `img = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/xKudh.png", "Graphics"];`

Comment: @bills You might be interested in Mr.Wizard's comment.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really an answer, but I sent the question to Wolfram. They replied:

The problem reported by you about SaveDefinitions option with Manipulate
was reproducible. It has been forwarded to the development team for further
investigation. You will be informed via email when it gets fixed.

I'll report back here if they respond.

Update: version 10.3.1 which is said to have "More robust import of image file formats, including JPEG and TIFF" still experiences the same odd behavior.